# Flutter Geolocator Not returning any result

Tags: android, flutter, dart, geolocation, location

I am currently using the latest geolocator that is 'geolocator: ^9.0.1'and for some reason am not able to get any data from the position function when i run

```
bool isLoc  = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
print(isLoc);
```

The result is true which i think means the location services are all enabled but when i run

```
Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
print('position');
```

nothing is been returned  i have tried all the accuracy values **low, high, best,lowest, medium** am really confused at what could be wrong i have also try it in the **initState** and also using a ***button**
Here is the full dart code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';


class GeoLoc extends StatefulWidget {
  const GeoLoc({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GeoLoc> createState() => _GeoLocState();
}

class _GeoLocState extends State<GeoLoc> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLoc();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
          getLoc();
        },
          child: const Text('Get Location'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  getLoc() async{
    bool isLoc  = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    print(isLoc);
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    print(position);
  }
}
```

Comment: What does it print?

Comment: only **true** is printed which is the result of isLocationServiceEnabled() nothing else is printed

Answer (score 0):

Below is your code modified, pls try it. you forget to ask for geolocation permission

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';


class GeoLoc extends StatefulWidget {
  const GeoLoc({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GeoLoc> createState() => _GeoLocState();
}

class _GeoLocState extends State<GeoLoc> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   getLoc()
        .then((value) => print("Location: " + value.toJson().toString()));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
        getLoc()
        .then((value) => print("Location: " + value.toJson().toString()));
        },
          child: const Text('Get Location'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  getLoc() async{
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;

    // Test if location services are enabled.
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      // Location services are not enabled don't continue
      // accessing the position and request users of the
      // App to enable the location services.
      Geolocator.openLocationSettings();
    }

    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        // Permissions are denied, next time you could try
        // requesting permissions again (this is also where
        // Android's shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
        // returned true. According to Android guidelines
        // your App should show an explanatory UI now.
        Geolocator.openAppSettings();
      }
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately.
      return Future.error(
          'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    }

    // When we reach here, permissions are granted and we can
    // continue accessing the position of the device.
    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  }
}
```

Also make sure you have below permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: still the same nothing is been printed here is the permission                                       ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />```

Comment: which mobile phone are you using android or ios ?

Comment: testing on a physical android

Comment: android os version ?

Comment: android version 9

Comment: try to uninstall app and re-install again.

Comment: been there done that, i have restarted my pc as well, i have also invalidate cache and restart android studio severally

Comment: i have tested above code on android 12 but i don't have android device with version 9. check app setting permission section see if location permission is allowed

Comment: all permissions are allowed can figure out what else could be the cause